# Recalculate 95% CIs for odds ratio for reverse reference group

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I am doing a meta-analysis and I need to recalculate OR and 95% CIs for the reverse reference group. For instance, I am looking OR for Q3 vs Q1 where Q1 is reference group. However, some studies reported the Q1 vs. Q3. So, I need to recalculate the OR and 95% CIs.
I found that it is possible to get the 1/OR for the odds ratio value. However, I am wondering whether is it possible to recalculate 95% CIs even when the study is not given the number of subjects for each cell.
Any input is appreciated!

For instance, I have the OR and 95% CIs as 1.14(1.02-1.30). This is for the low group compared to high group (reference). But I need to get OR and 95% CI for high group compared to low group (reference). In this case, how can I recalculate the 95% CI values. Is it possible to recalculate them? thank you again.

Comment: I think it should still be 1/OR.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I could not get the point well. Could you bit explain it more because I need to recalcuate 95% CI values but number for each cells are also not given in the study.

Comment: Why do you think you need the numbers of subjects for the calculations? What would be a situation where the number of subjects is not given?

Comment: For instance, I have the OR and 95% CIs as 1.14(1.02-1.30). This is for the low group compared to high group (reference). But I need to get OR and 95% CI for high group compared to low group (reference). In this case, how can I recalculate the 95% CI values. Is it possible to recalculate them? thank you again.

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information to the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To calculate the odds ratio for the reverse group comparison, take the reciprocal of the odds ratio. To calculate the confidence limits for the reverse group comparison, take the reciprocals of the limits and swap them.** Note: This is only valid for binary categorical predictors.

That is, $\operatorname{OR}_{BA} = 1/\operatorname{OR}_{AB}$ and $L_{BA}=1/U_{AB}$ and $U_{BA}=1/L_{AB}$. Here, $L$ and $U$ denote the lower and upper confidence limits for the odds ratio, respectively.

The reason is that in a logistic regression model, the odds ratio is obtained by calculating $\operatorname{OR}=\exp(\beta)$. If we switch the reference category, the coefficients sign is reversed, i.e. $\beta_{BA} = -\beta_{AB}$. Hence, $\operatorname{OR}_{BA} = \exp(-\beta_{AB}) = 1/\exp(\beta_{AB})$.

Here is an illustration using `R`:

```
set.seed(142857)
# Sample size
n <- 200
# Simulate one continuous and one categorical binary predictor
x1 <- runif(n, 10, 50)
x2 <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.75)
# Set up the linear predictor
linpred <- -4 + log(1.2)*x1 + log(0.5)*x2
# Simulate the probabilities
probs <- plogis(linpred)
y <- rbinom(n, 1, probs)

dat <- data.frame(y = y, x1 = x1, x2 = factor(x2))

# Logistic regression with "0" being the reference category
mod1 <- glm(y~x1 + x2, data = dat, family = binomial)

# Odds ratio and confidence interval
exp(coef(mod1))[3]
0.798159
exp(confint(mod1))[3, ]
    2.5 %    97.5 % 
0.3278559 1.9074099

# Reverse the reference level to "1"
dat$x2 <- relevel(dat$x2, ref = "1")

# Re-run the logistic regression
mod2 <- glm(y~x1 + x2, data = dat, family = binomial)

# Odds ratios and confidence interval
exp(coef(mod2))[3]
1.252883
exp(confint(mod2))[3, ]
    2.5 %    97.5 % 
0.5242711 3.0501203
```

You see that the odds ratio where $x_2=1$ is the reference category is the reciprocal of the odds ratio where $x_2=0$ is the reference category: $1.253 = 1/0.798$. The lower confidence interval limit where $x_2 = 1$ is the reference category is the reciprocal of the upper limit where $x_2 = 0$ is the reference : $0.524 = 1/1.907$ etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanations! I really appreciate it!

Comment: If your satisfied with the answer, you could accept it by clicking the checkmark besides it.

Comment: Yes, sure I did it. thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have one more question to clarify. Suppose I have the point estimate and the lower 95% CI, and I need to calculate the upper 95% CI. Could you let me know whether this formula is correct? Upper bound = Effect size + (2*Lower bound-Effect size)

Comment: @Ma0310 No, that doesn't seem correct. You'll need to calculate the upper limit on the log scale. The limits are symmetrical on the log scale. Then exponentiate.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment! But it is not clear for me how to get it in log scale? Is there any formula for it? Thank you!

Comment: @Ma0310 Take the logarithm of both the odds ratio and the lower limit. To be explicit, the formula for the upper 95% limit for the odds ratio is: $\exp(2\log(OR) - \log(U))$ where $\log(U)$ is the logarithm of the lower 95% confidence interval limit.

Comment: Thank you so much again for your kind response which is helpful for me!. Just to clarify whether I understand correctly, I could substitute the log of the lower limit for log(U), am I right? Also, if I need to get the lower limit using OR and upper limit, then the formula is: exp(2log(OR) - log(U) where log(U) is upper limit? Thank you!

Comment: @Ma0310 Sorry, it should be the lower limit, not the upper. So instead of $\log(U)$, use $\log(l)$, the log of the lower limits.

Comment: Thank you for your kind clarifications! For the upper limit: exp(2log(OR) - log(U) where log(U) is also right, am I correct? Thanks again!

Comment: I am sorry to ask your clarifications once again because I tried to apply this formula to get UL. But the answer is not correct. For instance, my point estimate (OR)=5.86 and LL=4.74. When I get the UL=exp(2log(OR) -log(LL), answer is 2.36 which seems not correct. COuld you kindly check this and correct me. Thanks!

Comment: Just remember that the confidence interval is symmetric on the log scale. That's really all you have to know. Applying this principle, you'll get 7.24 for the upper limit.

Comment: I appreciate your kind comment on this and it is pretty clear for me that confidence interval is symmetric on the log scale. However, I could not get the 7.24 yet. I got the difference of 2*log(OR)-log(LL) and exponentiate it which gave me 2.36. Did you also do the same calculation?

Comment: Finally, I found the answer. Thank you so much!